# Spring R2DBC + SQL Server: procedures query

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data-r2dbc

I am required to execute a stored procedure in a SQL server to fetch some data, and since I will later save the data into a Mongo and this one is with `ReactiveMongoTemplate` and so on, I introduced Spring R2DBC.

```
    implementation("org.springframework.data:spring-data-r2dbc:1.0.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("io.r2dbc:r2dbc-mssql:0.8.1.RELEASE")
```

I see that I can do `SELECT` and `INSERT` and so on with R2DBC, but is it possible to `EXEC prod_name`? I tried it and it hangs forever and then the test *terminates*, without success but neither failure. The last line of log is:

```
io.r2dbc.mssql.QUERY - Executing query: EXEC "SCHEMA"."MY_PROCEDURE"
```

The code is like:

```
    public Flux<Coupon> selectWithProcedure() {
        return databaseClient
                .execute("EXEC \"SCHEMA\".\"MY_PROCEDURE\" ")
                .as(Coupon.class)
                .fetch().all()
                .doOnNext(coupon -> {
                    coupon.setCouponStatusRefFromId(coupon.getCouponStatusRefId());
                });
    }
```

And it seems that no data is retrieved.

If I test some other methods with simple queries like `SELECT...` it works. But the problem is, DBAs do not allow my app to read table data, instead, they create a procedure for me. If this query is not possible, I must go with traditional JPA way and going reactive at Mongo side has lost its sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well. I just saw this:

https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql, version 0.8.1:

> Next steps:
>
> - Execution of stored procedures
> - Add support for TVP and UDTs

And:

https://r2dbc.io/2019/05/13/r2dbc-0-8-milestone-8-released

> We already have a few tickets lined up for the next milestone, and we know that they will require further SPI modifications:
>
> - Support for Auto-Commit
> - Connection Validation
> - Support for Stored Procedures